# AWS EC2 インスタンス で並列計算する際に CPUをフル活用できない

Tags: python, aws, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2 c5.9xlarge インスタンプを使用しております。
（36 vCPU, 72 GB RAM）
AMI は ubuntu 18.04 を使用しております。

python で並列計算を、36コア使って実施したいのですが、CPUを認識しないのか、一部のCPUコアが使用されません。
pythonスクリプトではCPUの数を36に指定しています。
（指定しなくても、自動でコアの最大数に並列してくれるはずですが、１コアでのみしか動きませんでした。
36コアと指定すると、25コア使ってくれるようです。）

top でCPU使用率を見ると、以下のようになっています。

```
top - 01:52:47 up 34 min,  1 user,  load average: 36.03, 34.15, 22.04
Tasks: 446 total,  37 running, 236 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu13 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu14 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu15 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu16 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu17 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu18 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu19 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu20 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu21 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu22 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu23 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu24 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu25 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu26 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu27 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu28 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu29 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu30 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu31 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu32 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu33 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu34 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu35 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 72028912 total, 63163192 free,  7853444 used,  1012272 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 10239996 total, 10239996 free,        0 used. 63486432 avail Mem
```

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3302 ubuntu    20   0  488808 235796  48848 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.20 python
 3304 ubuntu    20   0  528140 275044  48816 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.12 python
 3305 ubuntu    20   0  490244 236872  48652 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.16 python
 3306 ubuntu    20   0  493836 240756  48940 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.13 python
 3307 ubuntu    20   0  487884 234388  48496 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.19 python
 3309 ubuntu    20   0  475068 219924  46628 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.13 python
 3312 ubuntu    20   0  528812 275764  48848 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.13 python
 3316 ubuntu    20   0  491356 237732  48512 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.13 python
 3318 ubuntu    20   0  507600 254616  48820 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.14 python
 3322 ubuntu    20   0  529840 276740  48920 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.07 python
 3325 ubuntu    20   0  522588 268868  48348 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.11 python
 3328 ubuntu    20   0  508744 255844  48936 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.11 python
 3331 ubuntu    20   0  528416 275416  48876 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.11 python
 3333 ubuntu    20   0  497844 244440  48616 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.10 python
 3335 ubuntu    20   0  522516 268860  48436 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.06 python
 3338 ubuntu    20   0  493688 240256  48404 R 100.0  0.3  14:49.08 python
 3340 ubuntu    20   0  533152 279548  48484 R 100.0  0.4  14:49.07 python
 3370 ubuntu    20   0  509480 255976  48420 R 100.0  0.4  14:39.26 python
 3373 ubuntu    20   0  492532 239368  48748 R 100.0  0.3  14:32.92 python
 3375 ubuntu    20   0  493040 239400  48380 R 100.0  0.3  14:32.55 python
 3379 ubuntu    20   0  492884 239576  48688 R 100.0  0.3  14:27.08 python
 3382 ubuntu    20   0  531604 278160  48396 R 100.0  0.4  12:41.57 python
 3342 ubuntu    20   0  473212 219792  48540 R  99.7  0.3  14:49.06 python
 3377 ubuntu    20   0  479024 225260  48356 R  99.7  0.3  14:28.90 python
 3298 ubuntu    20   0  449504 194924  49564 R   8.6  0.3   1:15.02 python
 3291 ubuntu    20   0  522544 268260  49784 R   8.3  0.4   1:15.00 python
 3292 ubuntu    20   0  484124 229284  49460 R   8.3  0.3   1:15.02 python
 3293 ubuntu    20   0  524380 269692  49360 R   8.3  0.4   1:15.00 python
 3294 ubuntu    20   0  524916 270384  49528 R   8.3  0.4   1:15.00 python
 3295 ubuntu    20   0  485528 230932  49356 R   8.3  0.3   1:15.00 python
 3296 ubuntu    20   0  483012 228416  49536 R   8.3  0.3   1:15.00 python
 3297 ubuntu    20   0  447140 192612  49580 R   8.3  0.3   1:15.01 python
 3299 ubuntu    20   0  448776 194252  49688 R   8.3  0.3   1:15.00 python
 3300 ubuntu    20   0  442656 187712  49300 R   8.3  0.3   1:14.99 python
 3301 ubuntu    20   0  445364 190980  49580 R   8.3  0.3   1:14.99 python
 3303 ubuntu    20   0  447464 193128  49688 R   8.3  0.3   1:14.99 python
 3398 ubuntu    20   0   44236   4156   3228 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.80 top
```

複数のpythonプロセスが1つのCPUコアに押し込められて、パフォーマンスが悪くなっています。

手持ちのローカル環境（MacBook Pro）では、このような挙動は起こりません。
原因と解決策がわかれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

AWSの仮想マシン環境に起因する内容ではなく、LinuxあるいはPythonとそのライブラリ等に起因する話のように思われました。

topコマンド等でCPUが見えているわけですので、OSとしてはCPUは適切な数を認識していると言えます。並列計算ライブラリなどを使っているとかではなく、単にCPU数分プロセスをあげているだけですよね？

なぜLinuxがこのようにプロセスをスケジューリングしているのかはわかりませんが、tasksetなどのコマンドでプロセス毎にCPU IDを指定して実行してみてはどうですかね？

Comment: 以下のライブラリの並列計算オプションを使っています。
sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV n_jobs
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

tasksetなどで指定できそうでしょうか？